# Customizing the_content for wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress, function, conditional-statements

For my website I have created a `custom post type` to with `custom fields`.  While I have figured out how to display the custom fields into the loop, I found I could not take advantage wordpress's ability to use the_except, and consequently was my slider which runs on wordpress's the_except was empty.  So I came up with the idea of inserting my custom fields directly into the_content via the function.php.  This as has work well for the most part, but I'm having a few difficulties. I apologize, but I'm not very advanced in php.  So if the answer is simple please forgive.

Okay, problem 1:  I cannot get my image to show.  I have tried working the code a few ways, and the best I can do is get a URL or a broken image icon to show.

Problem 2: I have a few titles I want show prior to my insertion of the meta fields, but I want their appearance conditional on the meta field have a positive value.

```
function custom_post_type_default_content($content) {
global $post; global $wp_query;
if ($post->post_type == 'recipes') {
$content .= 
'<p> <div id="recipe_name"><h1>'.  
        get_post_meta($post->ID, "recipe_name", true).'
</h1><p></div> 
<br />
<p> <div id="recipe_image">  
        '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recipe_image', true ).'
        <p>
</p></div>
<br />
<p><div id="serves"><b> Serves:  </b>'. 
        get_post_meta( $post->ID, "serves", true ).'
</p></div>
<br />
<p><div id="prep_time"><b> Preparation Time:  </b>'. 
        get_post_meta( $post->ID, "prep_time", true ).'
</p></div>
<br />
<p><div id="wpcf-ingredients"><b> Ingredients:  </b><br />'. 
        get_post_meta( $post->ID, "wpcf-ingredients", true ).'
</p></div>
<br />
<p><div id="wpcf-cooking_instructions"><b> Cooking Instructions:  </b><br />'. 
        get_post_meta( $post->ID, "wpcf-cooking_instructions", true ).'
</p></div>
<br />
<p><div id="additional_information"><b> Additional Information:  </b><br />'. 
        get_post_meta( $post->ID, "additional_information", true ).'
</p></div>';}
return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'custom_post_type_default_content', 1);
```

This code actually functional, with the aforementioned exceptions.  Does anyone have any suggest as to how to add the conditionals into the code or fix the image?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be adding this in `functions.php`!

The content will be spat out in some kind of page, perhaps currently `single.php` and you don't want to edit single.php because it will have effect on all pages.

As it seems from your example, it is the `single` page for displaying `recipes`. So duplicate single.php; call the file `single-recipes.php` and work from there.

Have a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy to understand more about the file hierarchy.